# Java Copy File Forcefully

Tags: java, file, directory, copy, overriding

I have a method for copying files:

```
private static void copy(final String source, final String destination) {
    try {
        final File f1 = new File(source);
        final File f2 = new File(destination);
        final InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2);
        final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (final FileNotFoundException ignored) {
    } catch (final IOException ignored) {}
}
```

Is there a way I can override the "Access is denied" error when copying to a directory?

NOTE: I only need this for Windows computers.

Comment: You're sure you want this? I would recommend not doing this, and instead document that your tool/application must be executed with proper permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you're on UNIX, running the program as a user with write privileges for the directory will be required. Just curious, why would you want to override filesystem permissions? Why not just use the appropriate permissions?

Comment: I want to copy a file to the startup directory. Sort of like how Skype has an option to open at startup. The only problem is that on Windows 7 and probably Windows Vista, the administrator needs to confirm the copy.

Answer (score 0):

perm = new java.io.FilePermission("/tmp/abc.txt", "read");
hope this will answer your question

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void copyFile(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inputChannel = null;
    FileChannel outputChannel = null;

    try {
        inputChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
    } finally {
        inputChannel.close();
        outputChannel.close();
    }
}
```